# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000) & XML parsing

Tags: python, mysql, xml

I am trying to populate a column with an XML string in MYSQL. When I run my python script I am getting the below error. I am using the filename as the id, I believe I am parsing the XML incorrectly somehow.

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

```
cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

tree = ET

for a in os.listdir(mydir):
    if a.endswith(".xml"):
        print os.path.basename(a)
        j=ET.parse(mydir+"/"+a)
        a = ''.join(a.split())
        a = a[:-9]
        root = j.getroot()
        xmlstr = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8')
        xmlstr
        print a
        query = """UPDATE %s.%s SET col1= (%s) WHERE col2 = (%s)""" % (mysql_db,mysql_table,xmlstr,a)
        cursor.execute(query)
```

Do you know what is getting an error?

When I print query out prior to executing I get the below

```
UPDATE triageprediction.triagepredictionsamples SET CtXml= (<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<CAS version="2">
    <uima.cas.Sofa _id="3" _indexed="0" mimeType="text" sofaID="_InitialView" sofaNum="1" sofaString="The Enmore Practice
&#10;
more xml.....
    </uima.cas.FSArray>
</CAS>) WHERE REFERRALID = (1187116)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\XML_Formatter_v2\loadxml.py", line 47, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2">
    <uima.cas.Sofa _id="3" _indexed="0" mimeType="text" sofaID="_InitialView' at line 1
```

Comment: Print out the `query` before executing. What do you see printed?

Comment: Hi @alecxe, I have updated the post to include it, even if I add ("%s") it fails. I know I am doing something really stupid, just not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is in the way you are putting parameters into the query. Currently, you are using string formatting which is not only dangerous (see [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)), but is also a source of problems with putting the quotes correctly, escaping and data type conversions.

You should be using *parameterized queries*:

```
query = """
    UPDATE 
        {db}.{table} 
    SET 
        col1 = %s 
    WHERE 
        col2 = %s""".format(db=mysql_db, table=mysql_table)
cursor.execute(query, (xmlstr, a))
```

Note how the `xmlstr` and `a` are passed to `execute()` separately. Also note that we are not putting anything around the `%s` placeholders - the MySQL database driver would handle the quoting and escaping automatically.

But, we cannot parameterize database, table and column names, for this, we'll use string formatting. Though, make sure to properly sanitize the `mysql_db` and `mysql_table` variable values.

Comment: hey @alecxe is parameterizing table names still unsupported?

Comment: @NI6 yep, from what I know, it is not and likely never be :)